# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""?

Tags: java, mysql, awt

I appreciate if someone could help and tell why I have those errors. I'm working in a interface with java and I'm trying to connect with a database in MySQL, so I´m trying to get the date with this code

```
 Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();  
 int year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 int day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


 String d = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(day);
```

And I want to insert the date:

```
String query="INSERT INTO bitacora (id,nombre,apellidos,telefono,fecha,transaccion) VALUES ( "+Integer.parseInt(txtId.getText())+",'"+txtNombre.getText()+"','"+txtApellido.getText()+"',"+Integer.parseInt(txttelefono.getText())+",'"+d+"','"+txttrans.getText()+"')"d
```

But I get errors

```
No puede conectarse a la base de datos
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at interfaz.actionPerformed(interfaz.java:57)
```

Comment: one of your `Integer Integer.parseInt(String)` fails, as you probably pass a non-convertable string to it - as much as I can see, you forgot to fill out one textfield

Comment: [Don't build SQL strings yourself](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Eek - 1) use a PreparedStatement rather than building your SQL like this. 2) Use SimpleDateFormatter (or preferrably formatters from java.time) to format dates. 3) You haven't shown any code calling `Integer.parseInt` which makes it hard to tell where the problem is